# create Firestore index fails

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Running some firestore queries results with

> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: [https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/{projectid}/firestore/indexes?..](https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/%7Bprojectid%7D/firestore/indexes?..).

an attempt to use the link and create the missing index or trying to create similar index from scratch results with an error with no meaningful message, the index is marked with red icon:

[image]

when executing:

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite list
```

broken index has status: NEEDS_REPAIR:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| CICAgNiH4pIJ | ......-dev          | COLLECTION       | NEEDS_REPAIR | keywords                     |            | CONTAINS     |
|              |                                               |                  |              | name                         | DESCENDING |              |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------+------------------------------+------------+--------------+
| CICAgLjohJMJ | ......-dev          | COLLECTION       | NEEDS_REPAIR | keywords                     |            | CONTAINS     |
|              |                                               |                  |              | name                         | ASCENDING  |              |
```

I tried also creating that with Google SDK:

```
gcloud firestore indexes composite create --collection-group...-dev --field-config=field-path=keywords,array-config=contains --field-config=field-path=name,order=ascending  --field-config=field-path=__name__,order=ascending
```

it failed with the following message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.indexes.composite.create) {   "code": 3,
> "message": "Operation failed with the status: CLIENT_ERROR" }

The requested index references two fields: one array contains and one ordinary string field with ascending or descending ordering.
how to find out what's wrong with the index and how to 'repair' it?

Comment: You should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) to report problems with the console that don't have to do with your code.

Comment: @DougStevenson ok, submitted a ticket, let's see what the response will be like

Comment: I haven't seen a lot of these errors, so am askign around. Can you run `gcloud firestore operations list` to list all recent operations (i.e. index builds)? That should have some form of useful message.

Answer (score 0):

I made indexes generated successfully, posting here my findings in case someone comes across similar issue.
The indexes that failed to get generated referenced two fields: one was array, the other one was a plain string field. There were some documents in that collection that had the array field fairly big ~1000 values. Deleting document for which the array size was 500+ made adding index work fine.
I'm still not sure what exactly was wrong there, I know there exists a limit on maximum number of single-field indexes (40,000), as well as the [maximum size of an index entry](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#indexing_limits)  Maybe I hit one of those, if I did, I'm not sure how to prevent it.  The error message was not very meaningful.